# How to convert pandas column into rows given a id?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following pandas df:

```py
df = { "id" : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5], "name" : ["apple", "potato","lemon", "apple","potato","apple"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

I would like to turn name column into rows based on id. Desired output is:

```py
new_df = {1 : ["apple", "apple", "apple" ], 2: ["potato", "potato", ""], 3: ["lemmon", "", ""]}
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_df)
```

How can I do it please?

Comment: Check the #10 in the duplicate

Comment: @mozway @vojtam do we realize the `new_df` expected output has nothing to do with a pivoted version of `df`? The `id` column in `df` has `1, 2, 5` values, while the `new_df` columns are `1, 2, 3` ??

Comment: @jlgarcia `df.assign(col=df.groupby('id').cumcount()).pivot(index='id', columns='col', values='name')` seems pretty close, OP can `factorize` the IDs if they are not meaningful. Or maybe `df.pivot('id', 'name', 'name')`.